# How do i get Xcode 8.0 to tell me exactly which constraint is breaking (or how to debug xcode <private>?)

Tags: xcode, constraints, xcode8-beta6

I am trying to figure out how to reveal exactly which constraints are breaking in my code.
However, xcode 8 only returns `<private>`.
Any idea how to show these `<private>` objects?

[image: Xcode 8 console]

Comment: Well _that_ sounds like a bug! File file file.

Comment: Definitely a bug. When you use beta software, you are doing free QA for the vendor in exchange for being on the bleeding edge :(

Comment: I'm having this issue as well.

Comment: There was a talk at a Swift London meeting on how to use the Xcode debugger effectively. I wish i watched it more thoroughly, now i can't find it. I am certain it may have had a few pointers on how we could set up xcode to get more detailed info in the debug console.  Anyways if it is a bug hopefully we will get more information with this radar https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5022031137472512

Comment: Found it. https://realm.io/news/swift-summit-carola-nitz-debugging/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR;** The solution is to make sure you app has a [signing identity/certificate](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html). i.e a mac or ios development identity

---

Got an update from apple saying the issue was officially closed and was not a bug.  Suggesting to use breakpoint debugging to fully understand these objects. However going through my app details I noticed for some reason when I updated xCode the signing identities were not transferred. I [image]

And now `<private>` shows exactly what `<NSView>` or other object I am dealing with

[image]